# Importing UIKit/Foundation is not always necessary

Tags: swift, xcode, import

I'm trying to dig into this question for months now... I can't understand why, for some files I'm not required to import `UIKit`. Even if I'm using `UIKit` elements like `UIColor` or `UIImage` the project will compile without importing `UIKit`.

I've noticed that when I try to import `UIKit` for those files Xcode autocomplete marks it with a red line (here a screenshot). Is it related to what I'm asking maybe?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a bridging header which (directly or indirectly) includes the UIKit headers?

Comment: Oh.. yes. I'm doing it.

Comment: does it slow down compile time in your opinion?

Comment: I don't think so.